# Mock search filter using json-server

Tags: json, mocking, json-server

I have `routes.json` and `db.json`

**Route**

```
  "/api/*/_search?*=:searchstring": "/$1/?$2_like=:searchstring",
  "/api/*": "/$1"
```

**DB.json**

```
 {
  "cats": {
    "cats": []
  },
  "bats": [],
  "recordList": {
    "records": [
      {id:1, name: 'abc'},
      {id:2, name: 'def'},
      {id:3, name: 'ghi'}
    ]
  }
}
```

Absolutely fine fetching the record list with the above configurations.

Need to understand how to mock for the search filter call below:

```
http:localhost:3001/api/_search?name=abc
```

**Updated the routes to:**

```
{
  "/api/*": "/$1",
  "/api/_search?name_like": "/$1"
}
```

Following this link: https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/654#issuecomment-339098881

> But not hitting the config URL defined, what am I doing wrong? Am I
>   missing something here? The search term is dynamic, hence the value
>   passed should be acceptable from a variable only but in the comment it
>   is static. Kindly assist with this if anyone had similar issues and
>   resolved

If 'abc' is searched, it should return

```
{
  records: [{id: 1, name: 'abc'}]
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to write your search route like this:

```
{
  "/api/records/_search?name=:searchstring": "/records/?name_like=:searchstring"
}
```

Or even better, you can parametrize with `*` to `$1` replacement, thus you will be able to search for any parameter in query, and in any dataset, `records` or other:

```
{
  "/api/*/_search?*=:searchstring": "/$1/?$2_like=:searchstring",
  "/api/*": "/$1"
}
```

Afterwards your request to `http://localhost:3001/api/records/_search?name=ab` will be with response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abc"
  }
]
```

Additional [docs on routing](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#add-custom-routes).

Comment: Highly appreciate your answer @Andy Theos. But i am not able to resolve the issue with some stupid things. `/api/records/_search?searchTerm=abc` because of the `_search?searchTerm=abc` getting appended from data grid. Search term should address to `name` in my case.

Comment: Didn't quite get what you are saying, but i did update my answer with parametrized solution.

Comment: I updated my exact routing, plz check `_search?searchTerm=:val` should bind to: `{ records: [{id: 1, name: 'abc'}] }` using `name` as `identifier` key search

Comment: Yeah, check my parametrized solution with `*` to `$1`

Comment: there will be no `records` in the url here :(

Comment: `"api/*": "$1"` loads all records like: `{
  records: [{id: 1, name: 'abc'}]
}`, and `api/*/_search&searchTerm` should be some what to load the filtered records

Comment: There has to be `api/records` if you are using `"api/*": "$1"`. Additionaly you have to write search replacement rule first, so `api/*` wouldn't overwrite it. E.g. `{
  "/api/*/_search?*=:searchstring": "/$1/?$2_like=:searchstring",
  "/api/*": "/$1"
}`. Answer has been updated.

Comment: so how to handle it both? ill accept the answer. These is going big

Comment: can you please say where is name seach here: `{ "/api/*/_search?*=:searchstring": "/$1/?$2_like=:searchstring", "/api/*": "/$1" }` . Also how to handle all * records with another route if no `_search` url formed

Comment: There is a replacement for search, second `*` to `$2` in routes config. This is why `_search?name=ab` gets translated to `?name_like=ab`. Second rule will catch all other routes.

Comment: at present working fine for all(*) records as well as hitting the `_search` query string url as well. But not filtering for the name record as expected, intead loading all the records. Dono why :(

Comment: Paste your "filtering for the name record" and exact routes.json then, i got it working perfectly on my machine with aforementioned config.

Comment: updated my post with actual routes and db.json. Please have a look @Andy Theos

Comment: Wow, you changed the json schema... You have to flatten or write another route, e.g. no `recordList: {records: [...]}`, use `records: [...]` like you did before. If you want to wrap your response with `recordsList`, you have to look into [module docs](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#module). It is working perfectly fine with `records:[...]`, all other problems you posted in the comments are out of this question's scope. Cheers, hope this helps.

Comment: no i have not changed, * was always referring to records. Parent attribute was recordList. i just posted the minimal stuff

Comment: "Parent attribute was recordList", this was not in original schema :-) I answered your question regarding search mocking, you can try and figure other your problems with another question if you wish.

Comment: `*` is referring to `recordList` which displays `records`. not to be worried for `recordList`. How do i break that `records` & search.  `recordList` is the `routename` for your information. `/routeList` as `*`. This will conclude this thread